# Custom Attribute not added correctly in Reflection.Emit assembly

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

In creating a dynamic assembly using `Relection.Emit`, I am trying to create a method and decorate it with the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplAttribute`. I successfully create and save the assembly with the method, but when I load the saved assembly, my method does not seem to have any custom attributes. Here is my code creating the assembly:

```
ConstructorInfo methodImplCtor = typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplAttribute).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions) });
// stores the constructor I wish to use

AssemblyBuilder assm = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("MyAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
ModuleBuilder module = assm.DefineDynamicModule("MyAssembly", "MyAssembly.dll", false);
TypeBuilder type = module.DefineType("MyAssembly.MyType", TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Abstract | TypeAttributes.Sealed);
MethodBuilder method = type.DefineMethod("MyMethod", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, typeof(int), new[] { typeof(int) });

method.SetCustomAttribute(new CustomAttributeBuilder(methodImplCtor, new object[] { System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining }));

ILGenerator il = method.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

type.CreateType();
assm.Save("MyAssembly.dll");
```

After the above code runs, I grab the MyAssembly.dll file and reference it in a different project. When I run this code, it reports there are zero custom attributes on my method:

```
var attributes = typeof(MyAssembly.MyType).GetMethod("MyMethod").GetCustomAttributes(false);
// empty array!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because some attributes *aren't really attributes*, but are actually IL primitives. This applies to `[Serializable]`, and a few others - including (apparently) this one; here's the IL from "ildasm":

```
.method public hidebysig static int32  MyMethod(int32 A_0) cil managed aggressiveinlining
{
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method MyType::MyMethod
```

Note the `aggressiveinlining`.

Answer (score 2):

This is special attribute and, as stated in its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimplattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The members of the MethodImplOptions enumeration correspond to bit
>   fields in the CorMethodImpl metadata table. This means that
>   **information on the attribute cannot be retrieved at run time by**
>   **calling the MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes method**; instead, it is
>   retrieved by calling either the
>   MethodInfo.GetMethodImplementationFlags or the
>   ConstructorInfo.GetMethodImplementationFlags method.

So it is applied correctly, which you can verify by inspecting what documentation above says:

```
bool isAggressiveInlined = typeof(MyAssembly.MyType).GetMethod("MyMethod")
 .MethodImplementationFlags.HasFlag(MethodImplAttributes.AggressiveInlining);
```